# Moshi factory to ignore null values and use kotlin default value when deserializing from json string

Tags: kotlin, moshi

Based off of this issue in Moshi https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/843 there was some good discussion on why and how Moshi treats nulls the way it does. Although it makes a lot of sense to me, I unfortunately am working with an api that intermittently returns nulls, and the best feedback I've gotten is that we should just ignore them. In the issue linked above, one of the library contributors mentions this factory that could help.

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(CLASS)
annotation class DefaultIfNull

class DefaultIfNullFactory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
  override fun create(type: Type, annotations: MutableSet<out Annotation>,
      moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
    if (!Types.getRawType(type).isAnnotationPresent(
            DefaultIfNull::class.java)) {
      return null
    }

    val delegate = moshi.nextAdapter<Any>(this, type, annotations)

    return object : JsonAdapter<Any>() {
      override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Any? {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val blob = reader.readJsonValue() as Map<String, Any?>
        val noNulls = blob.filterValues { it != null }
        return delegate.fromJsonValue(noNulls)
      }

      override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Any?) {
        return delegate.toJson(writer, value)
      }
    }
  }
}

class NullSkipperTest {

  @DefaultIfNull
  data class ClassWithDefaults(val foo: String, val bar: String? = "defaultBar")

  @Test
  fun skipNulls() {
    //language=JSON
    val json = """{"foo": "fooValue", "bar": null}"""

    val adapter = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(DefaultIfNullFactory())
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
        .adapter(ClassWithDefaults::class.java)

    val instance = adapter.fromJson(json)!!
    check(instance.bar == "defaultBar")
  }
}
```

This works great, but isn't "optimal" for my use case because of two separate issues:
1. It requires annotating every class. I have about 200 classes that I would have to annotate and so I'm looking for a factory that would just do it instead of opting in. If anything, maybe I'd like to opt out, but that doesn't really matter right now
2. From the test that was also posted, it's not clear whether all of my values need to be declared as nullable. I'd also like to not have to mark every field as a nullable type, but the test seems to pass as `val foo: String, val bar: String = "defaultBar"` instead of `val foo: String, val bar: String? = "defaultBar"`

In order to get this working for myself, I converted the snippet to this. And it also seems to solve my two "issues" I state above.

```
class DefaultIfNullFactory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
    override fun create(type: Type, annotations: MutableSet<out Annotation>,
                        moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
        val delegate = moshi.nextAdapter<Any>(this, type, annotations)
        return object : JsonAdapter<Any>() {
            override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): Any? {
                    val blob1 = reader.readJsonValue()
                try {
                    val blob = blob1 as Map<String, Any?>
                    val noNulls = blob.filterValues { it != null }
                    return delegate.fromJsonValue(noNulls)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    return delegate.fromJsonValue(blob1)
                }
            }
            override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Any?) {
                return delegate.toJson(writer, value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I wasn't aware of a factory is that it moves across every field in a class, as well as the class, so when I initially had this, I thought that it would be perfect, but it does indeed get called for every field inside every class, fails the cast, then just returns the value.

I'm at the point where I'm happy with it, and I don't perceive any performance hits. Would anyone with more moshi experience say that it's completely terrible to do this, or it's probably the best I can get for my constraints?

**EDIT:**

Although I don't have an answer on whether or not this is a good approach I can confirm that this brought up two hidden issues and I can **NOT** recommend that you go this route.

1. Numbers that are longs in the json such as `1583674200000` won't work if you have adapted them to convert into a java String type. You would think you would get "1583674200000" but you actually get "1.5836742E12"
2. When you have a string number it will get converted to a double. So you might have a "100" but it will get converted to a 100.0.

This seems to be because numbers are doubles in moshi and the root cause is readJsonValue() as Map, as it first has to map all values into default values that moshi can understand in order to then filter out nulls. This is the cause of my issues.

TLDR Don't use this factory.

**EDIT 2:**
I've been notified that my Edit here is wrong. I'm not exactly sure it is, but we are discussing it here https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/843

Comment: I have copied and modified `KotlinJsonAdapter` and removed nulls from that and used default values. It works fine for your TLDR Don't use this factory cases. @coltonidle

Comment: @UmeshChhabra can you share a gist?

Comment: I have made some changes

https://github.com/uchhabra3/Moshi-Issue-843-Solution

If anyone want to check and comment
Side effects, bugs etc

Comment: @UmeshChhabra I haven't tried your code yet but I took a quick look. Looks really good! And thanks for all of those tests too! This should definitely help a lot of people out in the future!

Comment: Try to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66962109/10053046